# Is it possible to merge two Postgres databases

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, talend

We have two copies of a simple application that is based on SQLite.  The application has 10 tables with a variety of relations between the tables.  We would like to merge the databases to a single Postgres database with the same schema.  We can use Talend to facilitate this, however the issue is that there would be duplicate keys (as both the source databases are independent).  Is there a systematic method by which we can insert data into Postgres with the original key plus an offset resulting from loading the first database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1. Restore the first database.

Step 2. Change foreign keys of all tables by adding the option `on update cascade`.

For example, if the column `table_b.a_id` refers to the column `table_a.id`:

```
alter table table_b 
    drop constraint table_b_a_id_fkey,
    add constraint table_b_a_id_fkey 
        foreign key (a_id) references table_a(id)
        on update cascade;
```

Step 3. Update primary keys of the tables by adding the desired offset, e.g.:

```
update table_a
set id = 10000+ id;
```

Step 4. Restore the second database.

If you have the possibility to edit the script with database schema (or do the transfer manually with your own script), you can merge steps 1 and 2 and edit the script before the restore (adding the option `on update cascade` for foreign keys in tables declarations).

Comment: This is perfect - thank you!  I wish I could allocate more than one point!

Comment: Hello, 

That's quite an interesting approch but what if `id = 10000+ id;` results in a primary key that is already available in the second db ? for example `id = 10000+ 1 = 10001` and the second db's table happens to have an id of `10001` ?

Comment: @Sangimed - Of course, 10000 is an exemplary value. The actual *offset* should be determined based on the contents of the tables. Read the last sentence of the question, the author knows how to find it. In typical cases it is possible, though there may be situations that require additional action, e.g. changing the primary key type from `int` to `bigint`.